# Bug that does not respond after applying

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please resolve the bug in the code that why this code is not working after selecting the folder it selects the folder but afterwards does not do anything. I am unable to find the bug why code is not responding any help would be appreciate.

```
    Sub CopyPasting()
Dim f As Range, cell As String, r As Range, i As Long
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim xFd As FileDialog
Dim xFdItem As String
Dim xFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

   Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    Else
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
  Do While xFileName <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
      sh.Select
      Set r = Range("A3", ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
      Arr = Array(RGB(244, 204, 204), "Incomplete", RGB(244, 199, 195), "Incomplete", RGB(183, 225, 205), "Complete")

      For i = 0 To UBound(Arr) Step 2
        Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = Arr(i)
        r.Replace "", Arr(i + 1), SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Application.FindFormat.Clear
      Next i



      Range("A1:A2").EntireRow.Insert
      Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[3]C:R[1048575]C,""Incomplete"")"
      Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[2]C:R[1048574]C,""Complete"")"
      Range("A1:A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:AC2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Next sh
    
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
xFileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You never set a value for xFilename so you never execute the loop in  'Do While xFileName <> ""'

Comment: But what are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to iterate between existing files in that specific folder?

Comment: thank you i did it. and its working.

Comment: FaneDuru Yes i want to apply this code on a folder than have 10+ workbooks i was doing this activity for each file separatly before and now i have found Do while that can apply on a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want iterating between whole workbooks (from a specific type) in a folder, please insert this code line:

```
xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xlsx")
```

before of

```
Do While xFileName <> ""
```

If you do not want processing `xlsx` workbooks, please adapt it according to the need. For all Excel type workbooks you can use `"*.xls*"`...